# What PHP version supports this kind of assigning?

Tags: php

What PHP versions supports this:

```
function mytest($mVar = null) {    
    ($mVar === null) and ($mVar = "Hello"); // <--- This line
    echo $mVar;
}
```

Does it work in PHP versions lower than 5.3.x ?

Comment: My eyes want to bleed. This "works" because the `=` operator returns a value ("is an expression" like it is in C). It is similar to the questionable `$a = $b = $c`, the often-wrong `if ($z = 1) { ... }`, and the sometimes-okay `while ($x = fn()) { ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works on all versions you might encounter, there's nothing special to it. All of the operators (`===`, `and`, `=`) have been there since the dawn of time (official scientific term).

Of course you don't have to take my word for it; you can always **[see for yourself](http://www.ideone.com/8Xx3r)**.

**Edit:** Of course, I really don't see the point in the code above. You could have written the equivalent and simpler

```
function mytest($mVar = null) {    
    if ($mVar === null) {
        $mVar = "Hello";
    }
    echo $mVar;
}
```

or even

```
function mytest($mVar = "Hello") {    
    echo $mVar;
}
```

Comment: But that is only "proof" for down to 5.2 -- know of an online "codepad" for 4.x?

Comment: @pst: No, but we 're both pretty sure the operators were also there in PHP 4, and 3, and even before that. Also, pretty sure that their behavior has not changed over time.

Comment: Not what i asked. I know === works. What i asked is about the "and" part. This => Check if var is null and if it is assign a value, else leave it the way it was passed to the function.

Comment: @daniels: I don't only mention `===`, why did you pick that one out? `and` is the same as writing `&&`, only it has [lower precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was talking with a friend and he said that this only works in PHP 5.3.x and without an older version of PHP to test i asked here as he didn't believed me.

Comment: @daniels: Perhaps we was referring to `$mVar ?: "Hello"`, which [does only work on 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: Well he looked at the code and pointed at this. But, yes maybe he confused these two.